# Avconv get total duration of the encoding process

Tags: php, encoding, progress-bar, debian, avconv

We're working on a debian machine and testing avconv.
Is it possible to get the duration of the encoding process **before** we start encoding?
The aim of this is to get the total duration and display a progress bar (PHP).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate the duration of the file in its current form using ffprobe to then be able to determine what the final file size will be before you start.

Duration: if it is audio and video not yet muxed, you can use ffprobe on the audio file if the video file Duration says "N/A".

File size: you control the size of the output file using the avconv options such as video bit rate, audio bit rate, along with the length/duration of the video to encode as detected by ffprobe.

Here is an example for calculating file size for a 30 minute video using typical avconv option settings:

http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-February/005194.html

Use PHP (or better, an ajax call to a PHP back-end and animate using javascript or jquery) to update a progress bar as the size of the file output grows towards its final size.

Comment: Why was this downrated?

Comment: Because the haters on this site hate correct answers!